# API.AI for voice recognition on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording, dialogflow-es

I'm using [API.AI](https://api.ai/) for using voice recognition in an app.

I successfully download (*) [library](https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-ios-sdk) and run demo but I can understand a step:

- Is the S2T module (*Speech to Text*) included on library or the registered audio is simply upload to server and then processed?

Thanks!

(*) for those interested:

```
cd workspace
git clone https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-ios-sdk.git
cd api-ai-ios-sdk/ApiAIDemo
pod install
```

Open workspace and try

Comment: I didn't get the question. What do you need help for?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to improve question. Basically I can't understand if audio is processed(interpreted) client side or server side!

Comment: The audio is uploaded, see the docs reference, when they said "perform request using voice". https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-ios-sdk#5-or-perform-request-using-voice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's uploaded to the server and then processed.